# Multivariable Optimization of Microbes

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

It's been a while since I've had to do any optimization problems and I've been having trouble with the following question while trying to review calc 3.

Two competing microbes in a given region can be modeled with the equations
$$\frac{dm_1}{dt} = 0.24m_1-0.00006m_1^2-0.00002m_1m_2$$
$$\frac{dm_2}{dt} = 0.31m_2-0.000062m_2^2-0.0000207m_1m_2,$$ where $m_1$ and $m_2$ represent
amount of microbes. Determine the amount of microbe which will result in the biggest total annual microbe growth.

I guess I'm just having trouble figuring out what I'm maximizing. Am I supposed to maximize $dm_1dt+dm_2dt$? I assume once I have an equation then I just take the partials and set equal to 0 right? Any tips would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming $t$ is in years? If so then you're trying to maximize $\frac{d(m_1+m_2)}{dt}$.

Comment: Yes, you have the approach correct.  Just add the two equations, take partials and set to $0$.  You should get two simultaneous linear equations to solve

Comment: With the strict description of the problem, I'd say that it's actually a good deal harder than what you've supposed: The growth in a year (assuming $t$ is in units of years, so $\Delta t=1$) is $$\int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt}(m_1+m_2)\,dt=m_1(1)-m_1(0)+m_2(1)-m_2(0),$$ which is not identical to $\dfrac{d}{dt}(m_1+m_2)\cdot\Delta t$. *However*, the former can only be maximized by solving the system of DEs numerically. So presumably what's intended is that the instantaneous rate of total growth is to be maximized, which is what you're doing.

Comment: The solution depends only on the boundary conditions. Dynamics are fixed by the ODEs.